# WPF equivilent of unity 3D's Screen.lockCursor

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine

I haven't used Unity 3D but I gather you can use Screen.lockCursor to take control of the mouse for FPS games. Is this possible in WPF/Win32?

Obviously you have to release it when exiting or in the event of a crash

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer spread across a whole bunch of links, so

(1) Set a captureMouse flag, press once to go into this mode, again to come out, 
hide the cursor while you are in there

```
    bool captureMouse = false;
    private void viewport3D1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!captureMouse)
        {
            captureMouse = true;

            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
        }
        else
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;

            captureMouse = false;
        }
    }
```

(2) While you're in this mode constantly put the mouse back to the middle of the window

```
    private void theWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!captureMouse)
            return;

        Point windowPoint = WpfToRealPixels(theWindow, new Point(500, 500));
        NativeMethods.SetCursorPos((int)windowPoint.X, (int)windowPoint.Y);
        oldP = new Point(500, 500);
}
```

(3) Translate the co-ords

```
    private Point WpfToRealPixels(Window w, Point p)
    {
        return theWindow.PointToScreen(p);
    }
```

(4) To put the mouse back you'll need a native Win32 call

```
    public partial class NativeMethods
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetCursorPos")]
        [return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
    }
```

Hope that helps someone.